# Exported Community Template is missing all Compact Header components

Tags: lightning-community, community-builder, lightning-bolt, lightning-community-template

I'm trying to `export` a Lightning Community Template. My export is successful, and I'm able to generate a new community using my exported Template. But the new community generated from the template is missing

- Navigation User Menu
- Search
- User Profile Menu

All these components I can see and use from the community where I exported my template from. And I could not find a way to turn any of these options in new community I generated from using my exported template.

Below is how different my Compact Header component is in both my communities:

**[1.]** => Compact Header component in Community where I Exported my Template from.

**[2.]** => Compact Header component in Community which I generated using the Exported Template.

Please help how I can include the missing components in my Community Template or enable them in new community?

[image]

**My Community Theme Settings:**

[image]

Comment: I tried this in my Dev org but could see the components that you said are missing in my org.  Exported the template and created an Experience Builder site by selecting it in the Experience Creation wizard. Are you doing the same or are you Packaging the Experience Builder template for distribution? Thanks

Comment: Yes, ultimately, I want to package. But this is presently just done in same development org. I just configured my community and then used Export option to export as Community Template. Then within same org, I created a Test Community using the Template (I just exported) above. And the community created using the template was missing all these component options. I tried multiple times and same result.

Comment: @Swetha - I've updated question with my Community Theme Settings, may be these have different effects?

Comment: I've tried with the same Theme Settings but still can't reproduce the behavior you mentioned. I have used customerService Template.

Comment: I have created a new Dev org https://d5g000004jeofeai-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/?un=community712@salesforce.com&pw=Summer'21 and couldn't replicate the behavior here too. Feel free to login as needed and let me know your inputs. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. For some reason I'm still not able to generate community using it in my org. Though I just verified and got it packaged to create community in another org with necessary details like nav menu intact. May be I jacked up my community/template export in my other dev org.